# Extracting the coefficients of a quadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation

I'm just getting started with mathematica.  I can ask mathematica to solve simple quadratic equations:

```
3x^2 + 2x + 4
Solve[3 x^2 + 2 x + 4 == 0, x]
```

And it returns the roots:

```
{{x -> 1/3 (-1 - I Sqrt[11])}, {x -> 1/3 (-1 + I Sqrt[11])}}
```

How could I instead get the constants of the quadratic equation: a, b, c?

```
ax^2 + bx + c == 3x^2 + 2x + 4

a = 3
b = 2
c = 4
```

Comment: `SolveAlways[a x^2 + b x + c == 3 x^2 + 2 x + 4, x] `  Be careful to put a space between the coefficients and the independent variable, or use `*` for multiplication.

Comment: `CoefficientList[3 x^2 + 2 x + 4, x]` yields `{c, b, a}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (one) direct way is as follows: You get the coefficients of a polynomial with `Coefficients`. so if you have your equation as

```
eq = a x^2 + b x + c
```

and the "left side" as

```
ls = 3 x^2 + 2 x + 4
```

then

```
   Solve[MapThread[
  Equal, {CoefficientList[eq, x], CoefficientList[ls, x]}]]
```

delivers

```
{{a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 4}}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!